# How to send object list to layout once and for all?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, layout

I have mvc3 application with c#. Here, I always send some object list do every view. In every controller I declare

```
DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
```

In every view I write:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Categories = db.Categories.ToList();
        ViewBag.Brands= db.Brands.ToList();
        ViewBag.Products= db.Products.ToList();
        ...
        return View();
    }
```

in other view also I write

```
public ActionResult OtherView()
        {
            ViewBag.Categories = db.Categories .ToList();
            ViewBag.Brands= db.Brands.ToList();
            ViewBag.Products= db.Products.ToList();
            ...
            return View();
        }
```

In other controllers and their views I call same collection from db. Is there any way to write this code 1 time and send them to layout view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method in the controller to do it:

```
private void PopulateViewBags()
{
    ViewBag.Categories = db.Categories.ToList();
    ViewBag.Brands= db.Brands.ToList();
    ViewBag.Products= db.Products.ToList();
}
```

Then in your `ActionResults` just call it:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    PopulateViewBags();
    ...
    return View();
}
```

This is a simple way to do it, and it allows you to cache `PopulateViewBags()` so it will reduce trips to the database. And this allows you to have other `Actions` that don't need these `ViewBags` to work fine without taking a trip to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a base controller and create those lists in its constructor.

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    public MyBaseController
    {
        DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
        ViewBag.Categories = db.Categories.ToList();
        ViewBag.Brands= db.Brands.ToList();
        ViewBag.Products= db.Products.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then make sure all your controllers derives from this class. However this would mean every request to your application would make you fetch all the data in those tables. This may degrade your performance. You could think about fetching and displaying them asynchronously.